# Open zipped shapefiles in Java GDAL

Tags: gdal, shapefile, java

I have a .zip shapefile containing all the formats (cpg, dbf, prj, shp, shx) and I wanted to access them using GDAL. I've tried:

```
ogr.RegisterAll();
Driver driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile");
DataSource dataSource = driver.Open(file.getAbsolutePath(), 0);
```

and

```
ogr.RegisterAll();
DataSource dataSource = ogr.Open(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

I've tried these with file being .zip, .shp and .dbf, and all of them return null in the data source. I think it's not a lib setup issue, because I can open file geodatabase (.gdb.zip) normally. Am I missing something?

Comment: does it work if they aren't zipped?

Comment: Neither shapefile nor file geodatabase are shapefile or file geodatabase while zipped. Some tools may access them like that, but that is non-standard behavior.

Comment: @IanTurton Yeah, I tried uploading the .zip file, and the extracted .shp and .dbf files. None of them worked...

Comment: @Vince Yeah, I tried uploading the .zip file, and the extracted .shp and .dbf files. None of them worked...

Comment: If they don't work when in the filesystem, they're not going to work within a zipfile.

Comment: After unzipping the shapefile, are ALL components ('side-car' files) that make up the shapefile available to GDAL all in the same folder, with the same filenames?  (Just different filename extensions.)  There must be at least .shp, .shx, .dbf, .prj.  There may also be others, but (for most uses) at least these four components are required for a shapefile to work correctly.

Comment: Which version of GDAL are you using?  Versions prior to 3.1 cannot read zipped shapefiles at all.  Even with 3.1 onwards, the zip filename requirements are quite precise:  `Starting with GDAL 3.1, the driver can also support reading, creating and editing .shz files (ZIP files containing the .shp, .shx, .dbf and other side-car files of a single layer) and .shp.zip files (ZIP files contains one or several layers).`  See:  https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/shapefile.html .  It is unclear if they can be in a zipped folder, or all have to be at the top level of zip file.

Comment: Thanks, @SonofaBeach! The issue was I was referring them isolated instead of all together as you said.